# Can application throughput decrease if the heap size increases?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Quoting from [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html)

> If the heap grows to its maximum size and the throughput goal is not
>   being met, the maximum heap size is too small for the throughput goal.
>   Set the maximum heap size to a value that is close to the total
>   physical memory on the platform but which does not cause swapping of
>   the application. Execute the application again. If the throughput goal
>   is still not met, then the goal for the application time is too high
>   for the available memory on the platform.

And from [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/sizing.html#sizing_generations)

[Edit_1: I added the full paragraph below, which made me think differently after reading [the8472's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290261/897041)]

> The most important factor affecting garbage collection performance is
>   total available memory. Because collections occur when generations
>   fill up, throughput is inversely proportional to the amount of memory
>   available.

It seems to me that both sentences are contradicting.

It sounds to me that the first quote is suggesting that a larger heap size makes it possible or easier to achieve higher throughput (application throughput). The way I see this is that the application has a huge playground\heap to do all sorts of allocations without triggering a GC, so the application executes freely much longer than it would, if the heap was low, because less GC will freeze the application.

But the second quote states explicitly that throughput decreases if the amount of memory increases. Which sounds totally wrong to me ! Or could the second quote be referring to GC throughput ? That is the amount of work done by the garbage collector, which would make perfect sense to me then. But **throughput** is more like a jargon while reading the referenced tutorial and it means application throughput.
[Edit_1: I guess the quote is referring to the GC's throughput and not the app's]

What did I get wrong here ?

Comment: I think the second example use word "throughput" more as capacity than application throughput.

Comment: @TimWeber, application capacity ? It would still not make sense to me. I mean, why would the app capacity decrease if it's assigned heap increases ?

Comment: Capacity seems not to be the most effective word. Throughput in GC can be explain by the amount of work done by an application as a ratio of time spent in GC. If you had a small heap, the throughput will be very high because of the GC small processing time. If you get a huge heap, the GC will reduce the throughput due to his bigger processing time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you increase the maximum heap size relative to the amount of data that your application actually needs (the live set size) it increases throughput because the Parallel GC has to run less frequently and thus can work more efficiently.

On the other hand if the live set size increases but the maximum heap size remains constant the GC has to run more frequently to achieve increasingly smaller amounts of work, thus decreasing throughput.

Simplified calculations only considering the old generation ahead:

If your program tenures objects at 1GB/s, the collector moves objects at 4GB/s, you give it 100GB of RAM then and you have a live set size of 2GB then it will take 98s to fill up the heap and 0.5s to collect. Application throughput = 99.4%

If your program tenures objects at 1GB/s, the collector moves objects at 4GB/s, you give it 10GB of RAM then and you have a live set size of 2GB then it will take 8s to fill up the heap and 0.5s to collect. Application throughput = 94.1%

If your program tenures objects at 1GB/s, the collector moves objects at 4GB/s, you give it 100GB of RAM then and you have a live set size of 80GB then it will take 20s to fill up the heap and 20s to collect. Application throughput = 50%

Comment: Is that why regional GCs (i.e. G1) can be faster that others with huge heaps ? Because they partition the heap and work on those partitions individually. Instead of waiting for the app to fill up the whole heap before it (The GC) kicks in and have to deal with a massive amount of data stored in the heap.

Comment: How come the 1st and 3rd examples are manifesting differing full up times ? They both represent the same RAM size and tenuring rate. I don't think the live set size should make a difference because at the first example, tenured objects won't be collected unless the free heap size drops.

Comment: Your question is about the throughput collector, if you have questions about G1 you should ask them separately. As for the filling times, I am calculating steady state, i.e. where the live set size is already on the heap and only shorter-lived objects will need to be collected.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't get it wrong, the guide is contradictory, because the second paragraph you cite is wrong, or is very misleading (and define throughput as something different without making this clear).

The rest of the guide is however very good.

The error is also in the Java 11 version:
Java SE11, [HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide, chapter 4, Factors Affecting Garbage Collection Performance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/factors-affecting-garbage-collection-performance.html#GUID-5508674B-F32D-4B02-9002-D0D8C7CDDC75):

Chapter 4, "Factors Affecting Garbage Collection Performance":

> **Total Heap** 
>   The most important factor affecting garbage collection performance is
>   total available memory. Because collections occur when generations
>   fill up, throughput is inversely proportional to the amount of memory
>   available.

The rest of the guide does use the term as *application/system throughput*, and *throughput* generally is one of three GC tuning goals, so I consider this to be an error.

As far as I understand this should generally be the opposite:

> Throughput is generally proportional to the amount of memory available.

On your main question. I think there are tuning specific cases where application throughput decrease if the heap size increases. I can think of many cases where adding memory doesn't solve tuning problems, but I can't think of any where the throughput actually gets worse by adding memory.

[Java Performance by Charlie Hunt and Binu John](https://books.google.no/books?id=7mktLCw0E2IC&dq=editions:ISBN0137142528) presents the definitions and relations between *throughput*, *memory* and *latency* quite clear in chapter 7 "Tuning the JVM, Step by Step" page 256-257:

> **Throughput**
>   Throughput is a measure of the amount of work that can be performed
>   per unit time. A throughput requirement ignores latency or
>   responsiveness. Usually, increased throughput comes at the expense of
>   either an increase in latency and/or an increase in memory footprint.
>
> An example of a performance throughput requirement is “the application
>   shall execute 2500 transactions per second.”
>
> **Latency and Responsiveness**
>   Latency, or responsiveness, is a measure of the elapsed time between
>   when an application receives a stimulus to do some work and that work
>   is completed. A latency or responsiveness requirement ignores
>   throughput. Usually, increased responsiveness or lower latency, comes
>   at the expense of lower throughput and/or an increase in memory
>   footprint.
>
> An example of a latency or responsiveness requirement is “the
>   application shall execute trade requests to completion within 60
>   milliseconds.”
>
> **Memory Footprint**
>   Memory footprint is a measure of the amount of memory required to run
>   an application at a some level of throughput, some level of latency,
>   and/or some level of availability and manageability. Memory footprint
>   is usually expressed as either the amount of Java heap required to run
>   the application and/or the total amount of memory required to run the
>   application. Usually, an increase in memory footprint via an increase
>   in Java heap size can improve throughput or reduce latency, or both.
>   As the memory made available for an application is decreased,
>   throughput or latency is generally sacrificed.